# Is there a way to do an Image flow on effect with Onboarding Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is it possible to do an onboarding experience in Flutter? See the link below...

https://dribbble.com/shots/15798418-Mobile-App-Onboarding

As you can see as the user swipe right to the next screen, the image looks like it is flowing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have three images, one for screen and try using this package [Flutter swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)

I have done the same effect with this package

Comment: Great Package, Thank you!